# How would I rewrite this without an arrow function (regular function)

Tags: javascript

I'm not so good with arrow functions and would like some practice changing from arrow function to regular function. This is within React.

```
function render() {
  const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(
    item => <TodoItem
      key={item.id}
      item={item}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Removed React tag, as not React-specific question

Comment: Hey thanks for that. I did the exact same thing but now I'm getting this error: 

Error: Unknown error (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:138)

›TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleChange') (/App.js:41)

Comment: @codebling,  You're right, sorry I'm a bit of a noob.

Comment: no worries! That's what we're here for.

Answer (score 5):

## Arrow args

There are a few general forms of arrow functions.

- `arg1 =>`  is strictly for one argument
- `(arg1, arg2) =>`  more than one argument, enclose in parentheses.
- `() =>`  no arguments also requires parentheses

## Arrow braces

On the other side of the arrow, there are another 2 forms:

- `=> value` returns value (or the result of an expression)
- `=> {someStatements;}` does not implicitly return anything.

## Converting to `function()`

When converting to functions, follow this table:

- `arg1 =>`  becomes `function(arg1)`
- `(arg1, arg2) =>`  becomes `function(arg1, arg2)`
- `=> value` becomes `function(args) { return value }`
- `=> { someStatements;}` becomes `function(args) { someStatements;}`

## `this`: different for arrow functions

Lastly, a subtle but important difference. Arrow functions use `this` from their wrappers. Functions declared with `function` keyword always have their own `this`.

## Putting it all together

So in this particular case, given `todos.map(item => <Component />)`, the function is `item => <Component />` and working backwards from the table above we can see that this is equivalent to the function `function(item) { return <Component />; }`

The full line looks like this:

```
const outerThis = this; //save with a different name so we can access within function
const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(
    function(item) { 
        return <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={outerThis.handleChange}/>
    }
)
```

See also [Arrow Function Expression on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), where you can read about a few other arrow function caveats (like no `arguments`, `new`, `prototype` or `yield`)  and [`this` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation! To be honest, that's exactly how I changed it but I am still getting this error.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleChange') (/App.js:45)

This is as opposed to when I write it as an arrow function, where it works properly.

Comment: @beniboy ah! One other important difference is that functions have their own `this`, whereas arrows do not. Should put that in the answer

Comment: @beniboy updated

Comment: @Codebling, no `arguments` either in an arrow expression.

Comment: @Andy good call. Added a note with a summary of a few other caveats, including no `arguments`

Answer (score 2):

If you want transform an arrow function to regular function, follow this code:

```
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(handleMap)
    
    function handleMap(item) {
      return <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
    }
```

But, I recommend to use function components and React hooks. Read this artice: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html